# No automatic value conversion in wpf binding (IronPython)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, ironpython, nullable

I have a ViewModel with a property defined as

```
@property
def MeansOfTransportCount(self):
    return self._customerOrderTransportModel.MeansOfTransportCount

@MeansOfTransportCount.setter
def MeansOfTransportCount(self, value):
    self._customerOrderTransportModel.MeansOfTransportCount = value
    self.RaisePropertyChanged('MeansOfTransportCount')
    self.IsDirty = True
```

and the binding in XAML defined as

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MeansOfTransportCount, Mode=TwoWay,
 UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, TargetNullValue=''}"/>
```

The bound value is a nullable integer.

The problem is that no automatic type conversion seems to take place, as the type of `value` entering the setter is of type `string`, not `int`. Of course, an explicit value conversion fixes the problem, but normaly bindings just work without that. What could be the problem here?

Comment: Is making the property a dependency property an option? I don't know what options you have regarding hinting at what type the property is or if there are any alternatives in IronPython. Perhaps WPF would know whether it should perform the conversion if it had that type information.